# Moo tools, position a popup div based on the position of the mouse click

Tags: javascript, mootools

Using Moo Tools...
I am trying to position a popup div next to where I clicked the link...

http://mootools.net/more/docs/1.5.1/Element/Element.Position

There is a .position() option, and it looks like it takes an argument of 'div'. however I don't want to name every flippin element of a long table... I just want to pop up a div with item details...

currently the div positions itself in the top center of the document.. so if I'm scrolled down a long list, it scrolls my screen to the top....NOT what I want.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<tr><td id="Trans1234" ><a href="#" onclick="showTransDetail( 1234 );">1234</a></td></tr>
<tr><td id="Trans1235" ><a href="#" onclick="showTransDetail( 1235 );">1235</a></td></tr>
...{many rows}...

<div id="TransactionDetail" class="pop-up" ></div>
```

The JS:

```
function showTransDetail( transid ) {

    var newReq = new Request ({
        'url': '/getTransactionDetails/?id=' + transid,
        'method': 'post',
        'noCache': true,
        'data': {},
        'onSuccess': function( response ) {

            var dspDiv = $( 'TransactionDetail' );
            dspDiv.innerHTML = response; // this is working fine
            dspDiv.show(); // this works IF I use the next line
            dspDiv.position(); // this put the div top center of page

        });     

    }).send();

}
```

I have tried adding an id to the TD (not a solution I like, but it didn't work anyway);

```
dspDiv.position({
    relativeTo: $( 'Trans' + transid ),
    position: 'upperLeft',
    edge: 'upperRight'
});
```

This "kinda" works, but my screen still scrolls to the top, even though the div is positions by the element.... frustrating

Comment: Could you make a jsFiddle reproducing the problem so we can check it out?

Comment: thats because you don't prevent the default of the event so it goes to top due to there being a `href=#` on the element.